# C# Selenium: passing a variable into XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, variables, xpath

I am trying to pass a variable into my XPath, but I can't figure out how to do this:

```
string myVar = "Activities";
IWebElement webElement2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space(.)='Activities' and @_ngcontent-c32]"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by embedding the variable into the XPath string:

```
IWebElement webElement2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space(.)='" + myVar + "' and @_ngcontent-c32]"));
```

Comment: Or on newer C# versions: `IWebElement webElement2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[normalize-space(.)='{myVar}' and @_ngcontent-c32]"));`

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered . However, i recommended that you may add this method to your script to handle **NoSuchElementException** when your xpath is not found or invalid and also handle other Exceptions as well .

```
   public static bool existsElement(IWebDriver _driver,By by,int waitBySecond,string message)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, waitBySecond));

        wait.Message = message;

        try
        {
            // check _driver.FindElement(by) or wait element to check

        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message : " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);

            return false;
        }

        catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
         {
           Console.WriteLine("Message : " + ex.Message);
           Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
          return false;
         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message : " + wait.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);

            return false;
        }



        return true;
    }
```